# Angular 4 with Material UI - Sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am newbie-Angular developer and I'm learning right now.

In my project I want to make a simple page with a button and a sidenav (built with angular material) like the official material example (https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

The problem is that I want to make the sidenav in one separate component (like sidenav.component.ts) and the "homepage" in the app.component.

The homepage is full of stuff like paragraphs, divs, and I want to implement the sidenav (obviously with the onClick event functioning in the homepage) in every page without write "md-sidenav-container" in all pages.

[Here an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXw6.png)

What I have to do?

Comment: Place the `<md-sidenav-container>` in your root component and use `<router-outlet>` for showing dynamic content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Create a sidenav component

**sidenav.component.html:**

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side">
    Sidenav content
  </md-sidenav>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

**sidenav.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MdSidenav;

  constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sidenavService.setSidenav(this.sidenav);
  }

}
```

**sidenav.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
  private sidenav: MdSidenav;

  public setSidenav(sidenav: MdSidenav) {
    this.sidenav = sidenav;
  }

  public open(): Promise<MdDrawerToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.open();
  }

  public close(): Promise<MdDrawerToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.close();
  }

  public toggle(isOpen?: boolean): Promise<MdDrawerToggleResult> {
    return this.sidenav.toggle(isOpen);
  }
}
```

*(Don't forget to add the component and the service to a module!)*

In the AppComponent you can use the sidenav component like this:

```
<app-sidenav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-sidenav>
```

The router loads the components into the `router-outlet`. The `router-outlet` element will be placed inside the `<ng-content></ng-content>` (see sidenav.component.html).

The sidenav service enables you to control the sidenav component from every component of your application.

### Usage of sidenav service in header component

Inject the service inside the header component:

```
constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) { }
```

Create method to toggle the sidenav:

```
toggleSidenav() {
  this.sidenavService.toggle();
}
```

And in the markup you can use a button like this:

```
<button (click)="toggleSidenav()">Toggle sidenav</button>
```

---

**See small demo here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-kcszgq